# [(NSString) becomeFirstResponder];?

Tags: iphone

Hey does anyone know how to do something like:
[(NSString) becomeFirstResponder];
(where NSString goes thats where the textfields name is).
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: 1. Trying to send becomeFirstResponder message to NSString instance would fail wit exception. 2. Please explain better what do you need, cause it's not clear

Answer (score 0):

`[(NSString) becomeFirstResponder];`  will cause exception.

Use

`[textField becomeFirstResponder];`  to make your textfield as first responder.

where `textField` is the instance of your `UITextField`. Make sure that you have assigned IBoutlet for that.

Comment: Thank you for the snippet but i need to know how how to do something like: (NSString) becomeFirstResponder];

Answer (score 0):

If the corresponding view controller has instance variables or declared properties pointing to the text fields (e.g. `IBOutlet`), you could try:

```
UIViewController *containerViewController;
NSString *fieldName = @"someFieldName";

id field = [containerViewController valueForKey:fieldName];
if ([field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    [(UITextField *)field becomeFirstResponder];
```

Bear in mind that Cocoa Touch has a tag mechanism that can be used to get a specific subview from an entire view hierarchy *regardless of IB outlets, instance variables, or declared properties.* Tags are integers that can be set via Interface Builder or programmatically, and usually there’s a constant for each integer representing a tag. For instance:

```
static const NSInteger kFirstNameTextFieldTag = 42;

UIView *containerView;

field = [containerView viewWithTag:kFirstNameTextFieldTag];
if ([field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    [(UITextField *)field becomeFirstResponder];
```

You could extend this to feature a dictionary mapping field names (strings) to their corresponding tags, and then use the tag to get a particular field.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately the code does not work :(. Could you maybe post more to it? I have the tags, so even if you could make a textfield become first responder by its tag that would be great!